# Display an alert based on the json paylod value

Tags: json, api, alert

I have a JSON api returning the response as below:

{
    "formId": 2211,
    "formName": "Test Form Name1",
    "fileCount": 0,
    "createdOnDate": "2012-10-22T13:31:00",
    "modifiedDate": "2012-10-22T13:31:00"
  },

{
    "formId": 2212,
    "formName": "Test Form Name2",
    "fileCount": 2,
    "createdOnDate": "2012-10-22T13:31:00",
    "modifiedDate": "2012-10-22T13:31:00"
  },

This is displayed in the front end in a drop down as

```
<div class="select with-hover"><ul>

<li><a href="#" data-key="2211" data-value="Test Form Name1">Test Form Name1</a></li>

<li><a href="#" data-key="2212" data-value="Test Form Name2">Test Form Name2</a></li>

<li><a href="#" data-key="2213" data-value="Test Form Name1">Test Form Name3</a></li>
```

When the filecount is 0, how can I display an alert message when clicking the link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the fileCount data attribute to the `<a>` element. I'm totally guessing the rest of your code which you helpfully didn't provide:

```
$.ajax('your/url',{your:data},function(response) {
    $(div).append($('<a href="#"></a>').data({key:response.key, value:response.value, filecount: response.fileCount}).text(response.formName));
});
```

Then you need a click handler:

```
$(function(){
    $(div).on('click','a', function(e) {
        if ($(this).data('filecount') == 0) {
            alert('filecount is 0');
        }
        e.stopPropagation(); // stop click events on parent elements
        return false; // don't actually go to the href
    });
});
```

Comment: Just add a `data-filecount` attribute on your `a` elements. Then check it when the `a` is clicked.